# Why is a certain stage skipped in my Jenkinsfile when I use the 'when' keyword?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I apologise if this is a bit hard to articulate, please let me know if any more details are needed.

I am trying to get a function to run when there has been a change to the `requirements.txt` file

Here is my code:

```
stage('Testing push of requirements') {
    when{ expression { return fileExists('build-scripts/pushreqs.sh') } }
    steps {
        requirementsPusher()
    }
}
stage('Create Jira Ticket') {
    when {changeset "requirements.txt"}
    steps{
        jiraTicketCreator()
    }
}
```

The first `stage` block is irrelevant but it is used for comparison/reference.

When I run the above as it is, the `Testing push of requirements` appears in the build, but it completely skips over the `Create Jira Ticket` stage in the current build, where there IS a change to `requirements.txt`

Any ideas why this is? Could this be an incorrect syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `requirements.txt` file is not in the root directory, generally, the changeset contains the full qualified path of the file, hence try refining your file pattern. Example below.

```
when { changeset "**/requirements.txt" }
```

You can also print the changeset and see what you are getting. You can access the changeset like `currentBuild.changeSets`

Comment: Amazing thank you, that was missing!